# Is it good practice to recover a Kubernetes clusters etcd?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, backup, restore, etcd

We are in the process of designing our backup & restore strategy for our OpenShift clusters, and the question has arisen over the use of etcd and if we should restore using it.

We have implemented GitOps, therefore, the git repo is home to our cluster configurations - we plan to recover using the existing configurations.

However, should we be recovering etcd in addition to the cluster configuration, or is it best to rebuild from scratch?

Thanks for your forthcoming help.

Comment: etcd restore will likely provide your fastest time to recover, however rebuilding from scratch will likely provide the most consistent results (assuming you test frequently, etc)